# Is it safe just filtering out <pre> and enclosing with <pre>?

Tags: javascript, html

Some user generated text (likely containing scripts/codes) are going to be presented to the public. If I just filter out all the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags and enclose the resulting text with `<pre>` and `</pre>`, are there any chance user submitted script be executed?

Please give me an example of how to crack this protecting scheme.

Comment: `<pre><script>alert(1)</script></pre>`

Comment: Suggestion: Don't ask a question one way in your title and the opposite way in your question body. The answer to your title is "no." The answer to the question at the end of your text is "yes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe just filtering out `<pre>` and enclosing with `<pre>`?

No.

> ...are there any chance user submitted script be executed?

Yes, the scripts **will** get executed. You can try it yourself, just put this in a page:

```
<pre><script>alert("Hi there");</script></pre>
```

The `alert` is shown.

If you want to show user-generated content, a **first** step is to change all `&` to `&amp;` and then all `<` to `&lt;`.

But better to parse the content against a whitelist and actually leave out anything you don't want included.

Comment: Thanks for you kind answer. And I feel sorry not having tried carefully before ask. But if I `change all & to &amp; and then all < to &lt;` as you told, can any user get his javascript run when the web page displayed publicly?

Comment: @frozen-flame: I'm not seeing how. :-)